# Can I use CloudBees Jenkins Enterprise to avoid a connection issue of open source jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

I'm currently using [Jenkins open source edition 2.46.1](https://jenkins.io/) and facing 
[JENKINS-28476](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28476) connection issue.

I'd like to know if using [Cloudbees Jenkins Enterprise](https://www.cloudbees.com/products/cloudbees-jenkins-enterprise) could avoid this problem?

The company I'm working for is willing to pay money for commercial software.

Does anyone have this kind of experience?

JENKINS-28476 happens occasionally on our machines during a long (maybe 4-5 hours) build.

So it takes a lot of time to know if we could really avoid this problem by using Cloudbees Jenkins Enterprise edition.

The error message of the failed build is as follows:

```
FATAL: command execution failed
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ChannelApplicationLayer.onReadClosed(ChannelApplicationLayer.java:208)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ApplicationLayer.onRecvClosed(ApplicationLayer.java:222)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ProtocolStack$Ptr.onRecvClosed(ProtocolStack.java:832)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.FilterLayer.onRecvClosed(FilterLayer.java:287)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.onRecvClosed(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:181)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.switchToNoSecure(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:283)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.processWrite(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:503)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.processQueuedWrites(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:248)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.doSend(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:200)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.doCloseSend(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:213)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ProtocolStack$Ptr.doCloseSend(ProtocolStack.java:800)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ApplicationLayer.doCloseWrite(ApplicationLayer.java:173)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ChannelApplicationLayer$ByteBufferCommandTransport.closeWrite(ChannelApplicationLayer.java:311)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.close(Channel.java:1295)
    at hudson.slaves.ChannelPinger$1.onDead(ChannelPinger.java:180)
    at hudson.remoting.PingThread.ping(PingThread.java:130)
    at hudson.remoting.PingThread.run(PingThread.java:86)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Backing channel 'JNLP4-connect connection from 192.168.100.58/192.168.100.58:59504' is disconnected.
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.channelOrFail(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:192)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:257)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.isAlive(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$ProcImpl.isAlive(Launcher.java:1043)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$ProcImpl.join(Launcher.java:1035)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.join(CommandInterpreter.java:155)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:109)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:66)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
Build step 'Windows PowerShell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

where `192.168.123.123` is the IP address of the slave node.

It looks like that the connection from slave to master was broken.

Comment: We have the same issue and disable of ping thread didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the connection to the master was broken. CloudBees provides diagnostic tools and support services to help you diagnose problems like this which are usually caused by environmental factors like network devices interrupting the communication.